# Spring - Passing value to Controller from JSP GET method

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Applications: Java 6, Spring MVC 3.x, JSP

I am aware of modelAttribute for passing an object when using with POST. Say, we are creating a new employee then in JSP page, following can be used

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="employee">
```

My requirement is to **pass a single text box value from JSP page to controller**. Can you please suggest how we can do it?

I can guess that JSP page should have

```
<sf:method = "GET" ... >
```

but how a text box value (which will be inputted by used) be passed to controller? This value then can be used to search database.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to use form in this case. You can pass the value as a query parameter. When user clicks on search button just read the value using Javascript or jQuery and send as a query parameter.

```
window.location="myurl?q="+inputBoxValue;
```

Get this value in the controller from the request object

```
request.getParameter('q');
```

Or you can also pass it as a path variable (only if want to go to the Controller)

```
window.location="myUrl/"+inputBoxValue;
```

Comment: If he wants to use spring only then this is not a good approch